# Map and Let functions return "Error analyzing formula"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The formula below...

```
=let(a,unique({A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>""))),C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(2,1/(C:C<>"")))}),map(INDEX(a,,1),INDEX(a,,2),lambda(y,z,{to_date(y),z,join(", ",filter(D:D&IF(LEN(E:E)," ("&E:E&")",),A:A&C:C=y&z))})))
```

... combines and transforms values from columns A, C, D, and E into a new array that includes the date, the value from column C, and a concatenated string of values from columns D and E for each unique combination of values in columns A and C.

I'm trying to add one more column, the column B, but I'm still learning how to use Let and Map functions. This is what I came up with so far:

```
=let(a,unique({A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(3,1/(A:A<>""))),C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(3,1/(C:C<>""))),B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(3,1/(B:B<>"")))}),map(INDEX(a,,1),INDEX(a,,2),INDEX(a,,3),lambda(y,z,f{to_date(y),z,join(", ",filter(D:D&IF(LEN(E:E)," ("&E:E&")",),A:A&C:C=y&z&f))})))
```

But it doesn't work.

Raw data:

[image: Sheet]

Current output from original formula:
[image]

The desired output would add the column B along with the current o output.
If anyone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: But you do not have anything to Column B.

Comment: Sorry, there will be. Column B will never be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a comma between the `f` and curly bracket. When you're defining names in lambda you should separate them with commas and one more comma before the following formula expression

Comment: Thanks! I still had to modify some other things beside to missing comma, but you put me in the right path. Here's the fully corrected formula for whoever ends up here: =let(a,unique({A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(3,1/(A:A<>""))),C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(3,1/(C:C<>""))),B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(3,1/(B:B<>"")))}),map(INDEX(a,,1),INDEX(a,,2),INDEX(a,,3),lambda(y,z,f,{to_date(y),f,z,join(", ",filter(D:D&IF(LEN(E:E)," ("&E:E&")",),A:A&C:C&B:B=y&z&f))})))